# Cannot read property of null in HTML and JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

I am new to JS. I was trying to make a button which will change the BG color of the HTML page.
This is HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <script src="js/index.js"></script>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary">Click Me!</button>
</body>
</html>
```

and here is the JS:

```
const button = document.querySelector('button');
const body = document.querySelector('body');
const colors = ['red', 'green', 'blue', 'yellow', 'pink', 'purple'];

body.style.backgroundColor = 'violet';
button.addEventListener('click', changeBackground);

function changeBackground(){
const colorIndex= parseInt(Math.random()*colors.length);
body.style.backgroundColor = colors[colorIndex];
}
```

this code is not working and it is constantly giving error on console

> index.js:5 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null

Comment: works: https://jsfiddle.net/e1mdu8h2/. bod your script below the body

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put your script to execute after your body loaded

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>

    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary">Click Me!</button>
    <script src="js/index.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: so it worked for few minutes. Now i tried to check if it works correctly, it is again giving me the same error.

Comment: it should work, place it inside the body at the end